# How to use Globalize with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, globalize, cldr

How do I load the [Globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize) library along with the CLDR data in an Angular app generated from angular cli. When I perform the following steps:

1. `npm install globalize cldr-data`
2. `import {Globalize} from 'globalize';` in `app.component.ts`
3. `ng serve`

I get this error:

```
Can't resolve 'cldr' in '/Users/temp-user/cldr-app/node_modules/globalize/dist'
 @ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize.js 22:2-25:14
 @ ./~/globalize/dist/node-main.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

EDIT:

Also tried including it in `scripts` in `angular-cli.json`

```
  "scripts": [
     "../node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr.js",
     "../node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize.js"
  ],
```

Comment: is it resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

just including any library wont suffice to use it, you need to configure it in `angular-cli.json` file.

```
"scripts": [
  ... path to global libraray
]
```

Read more about [Global Library Installation here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib).

Comment: i still get that error when i included it in `scripts` in `angular-cli.json`

Comment: @takeradi, did you add path to `cldr` libraray as well in cli-json?